# How will see the bot conversation count by adding telemetry in bot framework code?

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-application-insights, telemetry

How will see the conversation counts in application insights?

[I have added telemetry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-telemetry?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) in my bot , still I am not able to see conversation counts and other than conversation counts.

```
const{ApplicationInsightsTelemetryClient,TelemetryInitializerMiddleware=require('botbuilder-applicationinsights');
const { TelemetryLoggerMiddleware } = require('botbuilder-core');


var telemetryClient = getTelemetryClient(process.env.InstrumentationKey);
var telemetryLoggerMiddleware = new TelemetryLoggerMiddleware(telemetryClient);
var initializerMiddleware = new TelemetryInitializerMiddleware(telemetryLoggerMiddleware);

whatsAppAdapter.use(initializerMiddleware);
AppAdapter.use(initializerMiddleware)

dialog.telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
bot.telemetryClient = telemetryClient;

 function getTelemetryClient(instrumentationKey) {
        if (instrumentationKey) {
            return new ApplicationInsightsTelemetryClient(instrumentationKey);
        }
        return new NullTelemetryClient();
    }`.
```

I am using bot framework for my bot, how should get conversation counts?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When asking a question it's best to provide what you have tried, but I think I can provide some general guidance. I have used a different method to capture telemetry on my bots (older method I believe).

```js
const appInsights = require('applicationinsights');
appInsights.setup(process.env.APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY).start();
const appInsightsClient = appInsights.defaultClient;
```

I'm making an assumption that this collects similar data as the method you linked. This telemetry creates a custom "Activity" event that you can use to count your conversations. I split mine out by channel, then summarize by binned timestamp, channel, and conversation ID to get the number of messages per conversation, then by binned timestamp and channel to get the number of conversations.

```
customEvents
  | where name == 'Activity'
  | extend channel = customDimensions['channel']
  | extend channel = tostring(iff(isnull(channel), customDimensions['Channel ID'], channel))
  | extend conversationID = tostring(customDimensions['Conversation ID'])
  | order by timestamp desc
  | summarize message_count = count() by bin(timestamp, 1d), conversationID, channel
  | where message_count > 4
  | summarize conversation_count = count() by bin(timestamp, 1d), channel
  | order by timestamp asc
```

This as a solution is dependent on if your telemetry is creating this custom event in App Insights or something different, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.